# Finding table elements by xpath using Selenium returns only the elements present in html source, though the xpath highlights all elements in inspect

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape data from a table from this website: https://prosettings.net/cs-go-pro-settings-gear-list/. Mouse sensitivity is the first value I've been trying to scrape. All desired elements are highlighted within inspect/developer tools when searching by this xpath: //table[@id="table_1"]/tbody/tr/td[8].

Grabbing table elements using webdriverwait and find_elements_by_xpath and using this xpath above returns only 10 of the same elements out of around 475 in the table, even when using webdriverwait to give everything a chance to load, and when using scrollIntoView in case the issue may be that the data won't load without scrolling. The only thing that these 10 elements have in common is that they are the only elements present in the html source code out of the 475, which I did not think would be an issue since I am using selenium and searching by xpath. Here is my code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


PATH = r"your own chromedriver path here" 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = PATH) 
driver.get("https://prosettings.net/cs-go-pro-settings-gear-list/")
rows = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//table[@id="table_1"]/tbody/tr/td[8]')))
for row in rows:
    print(row.get_attribute('innerHTML')) 

driver.close()
```

For me, this returns only those values of mouse sensitivity you could find in the html source :

```
2.00
2.40
1.90
2.00
1.87
1.60
1.00
2.20
2.00
3.20
```

I cant seem to figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

We need to first scroll so that the table is visible and then scroll to each rows. Try something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path to chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://prosettings.net/cs-go-pro-settings-gear-list/")
time.sleep(10) # Takes time load page.
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='table_1']") #Find the table scroll into view.
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",table)
i = 0
try:
    while True:
        rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='table_1']/tbody/tr/td[7]")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",rows[i])#Find the rows and scroll into view.
        print(rows[i].text)
        i+=1
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
print("Total number of rows = {}".format(i))
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
1.45
2.20
3.09
...
list index out of range
Total number of rows = 475
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually not sure if that's the best way to do it but the following worked for me in the past:

```
driver.get("https://prosettings.net/cs-go-pro-settings-gear-list/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//table[@id="table_1"]/tbody/tr/td[8]')))
html = driver.page_source
```

Then do your scraping on `html`.

Find more on my approach here: https://simplepush.io/blog/python-web-scraping-javascript-with-selenium